# How to select a tab from TabCointainer (AjaxToolKit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs, tabcontainer

How can I select a tab programmatically of a TabContainer?  and also how can I get the selected Tab?

Comment: I haven't touched those in awhile, but off the top of my head, I beilive it has a SelectedIndex property you can set to change the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete list of `TabContainer`'s properties taken from [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx):

```
TabContainer Properties

    ActiveTabChanged (Event) - Fired on the server side when a tab is changed after a
postback
    OnClientActiveTabChanged - The name of a javascript function to attach to the
client-side tabChanged event
    CssClass - A css class override used to define a custom look and feel for the tabs.
See the Tabs Theming section for more details.
    ActiveTabIndex - The first tab to show
    Height - sets the height of the body of the tabs (does not include the TabPanel
headers)
    Width - sets the width of the body of the tabs
    ScrollBars - Whether to display scrollbars (None, Horizontal, Vertical, Both, Auto)
in the body of the TabContainer
    TabStripPlacement - Whether to render the tabs on top of the container or below
(Top, Bottom)
```

Useful links with sample code:

http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/04/setting-focus-to-particular-tab-in.html

```
tabContainer = tabContainer.control;
//Retrieving the tab using the get_activeTab method/property
var tab = tabContainer.get_activeTab();
var headerText = tab.get_headerText();
alert(headerText);
//Another way of retrieving the tab using the get_previousTab method/property
tab = tabContainer.getPreviousTab();
alert(tab.get_tabIndex());
```

[3 Tips for Working with the AjaxControlToolkit's TabContainer Control](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/3_tips_for_working_with_the_aj.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Tab Index like...

```
tbcName.ActiveTabIndex = 3;
```

and similarly

```
tbcName.ActiveTabIndex// Return active tab index
```

Please note, tab Index start from `0`

Comment: When I click on my Submit button and I am on tab 3, on Postback it is still bringing me to the first tab.. i want to come back on the tab index i had selected

Comment: Tab control does not maintain tab index on postback, have a check these links http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/maintaining-active-tab.aspx    http://forums.asp.net/p/1300797/2548838.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
yourTabContainer.ActiveTab = tabIndex;
```

Comment: This throws an error can not convert from int to AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel