# ajax active tab id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

i have an ajax control toolkit tabcontainer. How can i determine the ID of the active tab using javascript or jquery?
i.e below it would be Tab_Monitor if that tab was active.

I have tried all the samples but cannot find the solution.

thanks
damo

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainerMain" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="4" Width="100%"
Height="100%" CssClass="" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
   <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="test" ID="Tab_Monitor">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <div class="TabControls">
             <p>Howdy, I'm in Section Tab_Monitor.</p>
         <div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code not tested. As I can remeber, when any tab is selected, .ajax__tab_active class is applied to that div. So the following can be used to grab the ID of the selected tab

```
alert($(".ajax__tab_active").first().attr('id'));
```

You can customize the selector based on your need.

Comment: Thanks very much. doesn't give me the exactly  the Tab ID but it will work . the value it returns is TabContainerMain_Tab_Monitor_Tab , where i had expected just the ID of the tab which is Tab_Monitor

Comment: I am glad that it worked. As it has a runat="server" tag, the generated id will be different than the declared id of that control.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax Control Toolkit TabContainer client side component supports get_activeTab and get_activeTabIndex methods.

You can access this methods using the following JS code:

```
$find('<%=TabContainerMain.ClientID %>').get_activeTab();
```

**Edit:**

You can also review [How to select a tab from TabCointainer (AjaxToolKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832520/how-to-select-a-tab-from-tabcointainer-ajaxtoolkit) where guys suggest the same.